# Run Script as new content loaded , how can i listen to DOM change?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

Hi im working on a Chrome extension that adds badges to users, now the problem is i have to refresh the page everytime so the badges can load because there are  client-side changes . How can i watch events change so i run the function on first time page load ?
I read something about input event listener or MutationObserver but im not sure how can i implement that , Any help would be much appreciated .
CODE:

```
function Foreground() {
  let users = null;
  let queries = [];
  let userIds = [];

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {});
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    fetchUsersAndQueries();
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async(message, sender, res) => {
      if (message.users) {
        fetchUsersAndQueries();

        if (users) {
          return res(users);
        } else {
          return res([]);
        }
      }

      if (message.refresh) {
        try {
          assignBadges();
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error.message);
        }
      }

      return true;
    });

    let done = false;
    setInterval(() => {
      if (done) {
        return;
      }
      if (users) {
        done = true;

        try {
          assignBadges();
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error.message);
        }


      }
    }, 500);
  });

  async function fetchUsersAndQueries() {
    userIds = await getAPIUserIds();

    let isStop = false;

    setInterval(() => {
          if (isStop) {
            return;
          }

          const parasiteContainer = document.querySelector('#parasite-container');
          if (parasiteContainer) {
            if (parasiteContainer.shadowRoot) {
              try {
                const roster1 = parasiteContainer.shadowRoot.querySelector(`[name="roster1"]`);
                const roster2 = parasiteContainer.shadowRoot.querySelector(`[name="roster2"]`);

                if (!roster1) {
                  return
                };

                if ([...roster1.children].length === 1) {
                  if (roster1.firstElementChild.children.length === 1) {
                    if (roster1.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.length === 1) {
                      const fTeam = [...roster1.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.children].map(item => getUsername(item));
                      const sTeam = [...roster2.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.children].map(item => getUsername(item));
                      users = fTeam.concat(sTeam).flat();
                      queries.push([...roster1.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.children]);
                      queries.push([...roster2.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.children]);
                      isStop = true;
                    } else {
                      const fTeam = [...roster1.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.children].map(item => getUsername(item));
                      const sTeam = [...roster2.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.children].map(item => getUsername(item));
                      users = fTeam.concat(sTeam).flat();
                      queries.push([...roster1.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.children]);
                      queries.push([...roster2.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.children]);
                      isStop = true;
                    }
                  } else {
                    const fTeam = [...roster1.firstElementChild.children].map(item => getUsername(item));
                    const sTeam = [...roster2.firstElementChild.children].map(item => getUsername(item));
                    users = fTeam.concat(sTeam).flat();
                    queries.push([...roster1.firstElementChild.children]);
                    queries.push([...roster2.firstElementChild.children]);
                    isStop = true;
                  }
                }

                queries.forEach(query => {
                  query.map(item => {
                    if (item.children.length > 1) {
                      [...item.children].map(child => {
                        // const container = child.querySelector('.sc-hCQDas'); // Classname might change in the future.
                        const container = child.firstElementChild ? .firstElementChild ? .firstElementChild ? .firstElementChild ? .children[2];
                        if (container) {
                          container.insertAdjacentHTML(
                            'beforeend',
                            createBadge(badgesResponse.data.exists, child.dataset.userId)
                          );
                        }
                      });
                    } else {
                      // const container = item.querySelector('.sc-hCQDas'); // Classname might change in the future.
                      const container = item.firstElementChild ? .firstElementChild ? .firstElementChild ? .children[0];
                      if (container) {
                        container.insertAdjacentHTML(
                          'beforeend',
                          createBadge(badgesResponse.data.exists, item.dataset.userId)
                        );
                      }
                    }

                  });
                });
              }
```

Comment: [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) does seem appropriate to your requirements

Comment: What part of using MutationObserver are you having trouble with? You can put all your code into a named function. Then you can call it from both the `load` event listener and the MutationObserver callback.

Comment: But you might want to refine the code for the MutationObserver, so it just updates the badge on the element that changed, rather than looping over all users.

Comment: so  i should create a load.js and add smth like this so it checks the subtree for children modifications ,  `  const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(entries=> {
    console.log(entries)
})
const parent=document.querySelector('#parasite-container')
mutationObserver.observe(parent,{
    subtree:true,
    childList: true,
    characterData:true

}) `